# Move partition from LVM to physical drive

Tags: lvm

In the process of external HDD recovery, I backed-up the whole disk to LVM LV, run fsck and resize2fs to fit into new drive (both external USB HDD, but the newer one is few MB smaller). 
I used ddrescue to copy the data into the LV.
Now, when I use dd to copy data from the LV to the physical drive I get broken partition table.
When I fix the partition table (to be same as the LV's partition table) I get errors from fsck.

I run
`dd bs=100M if=/dev/mapper/backup--vg-backup--lv of=/dev/sdh`
to get the data from the LV to the physical drive.

Both LV and physical drive use same logical/physical sector size.

My question is how to copy data from LV (which contains a whole disk) back to physical disk?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `fdisk` and `fsck` used cached data even after issuing `partprobe`.
This made fdisk use wrong partition table and fsck wrong superblock.

I tried to **reboot** the machine and both fdisk and fsck reported expected results, but moreover the same results for the physical disk and the LV.

I was expecting the FS might report some errors (all of 4TB but 2MB were recovered from the original disk to the LV), but I mounted the partition on the physical drive and the files appear to be OK.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to manually create a new partition table on the target hdd/sdd, recreate the filesystem(s) and copy the data from the LVM-drive.

I personally use `rsync -avxHAX (source) (target)` for that.

Comment: The following answer apparently has performance improvements for the command that you are posting, https://superuser.com/a/1185401/89031.